# What are these nonsense paragraphs in Stephen Baxter's Weaver?

Tags: stephen-baxter, weaver

> I'm sorry for the bad quality. However we really did as what you
>   said. To make things clear, could you please give me name of jobs with
>   bad quality? If possible, the errors with picture. Only told us what's
>   problem is no enough, The more pictures you can send to us, the more
>   clearly we can understand what's the problem.

This shows up multiple times in Weaver at the beginning of Part 3.

I wasn't able to make sense of why this shows up several times, apparently separated from the story. I get the feeling it's an indication of wobbles in the timestream, but I don't see any other references to it in the book.

Here's a [link](https://books.google.ca/books?id=HHZAFO2XiHMC&pg=PT236&lpg=PT236&dq=I%27m%20sorry%20for%20the%20bad%20quality.%20However%20we%20really%20did%20as%20what%20you%20said.&source=bl&ots=WTPPWbsJC2&sig=475X3q6X4N3hDEjVEurfOgRi4FQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=32QUVYaQE7PIsATuj4GADg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=I%27m%20sorry%20for%20the%20bad%20quality.%20However%20we%20really%20did%20as%20what%20you%20said.&f=false) and some screenshots showing what I'm talking about.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That link, plus the one you commented in Richard's answer, are just linking to the book's Amazon page (rather than a page of text). Might just be my browser being stupid, but I thought I'd let you know in case you pasted the wrong link :)

Comment: When I follow it, I end up at Google Books, and it shows the text of the book...

Comment: Dunno why I said Amazon, I meant Google XD but no text, on any browser. But it must be me then, just wanted to check you did have the right link :)

Comment: @Almo I see the same thing you do when I click the link.  Richard's answer is probably correct, or at least close to the truth - it is evidence of some kind of miscommunication between the editor and publisher, although this makes it very puzzling that the person responsible for the error uses broken English.  An editor would presumably know proper grammar and sentence structure.

Comment: @Almo - Were you reading a hard copy (as in, a physical book), or an eBook version?

Comment: You can contact him to ask about it through this page: http://www.stephen-baxter.com/contact.html

Comment: Woops! I totally forgot about this. Thanks for the beep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather amusingly, this 'rogue paragraph' appears to be a comment from the book's editor that has somehow crept into the ebook version.

As you can see [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=it0WDM1xhPgC&pg=PT162&lpg=PT162&dq=weaver%20%22thump%20me%20again%22&source=bl&ots=ptdSxLnT1x&sig=XHohOM90p80KzYAXWhHtQxFkmXo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-WAUVYnTEobMOOu3gLgK&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=weaver%20%22thump%20me%20again%22&f=false), in the google books version the paragraph doesn't appear.

> The air in the farmhouse kitchen was a mass of cigarette smoke and
>   steamy cooking smells.
>
> ‘*I’m telling you you’re not going out again
>   dressed like a bloody little tart.*’
>
> '*What are you going to do, Dad, thump me again*?’   Sitting at the
>   kitchen table, Ernst sighed.

Comment: I see it in Google books:

https://books.google.ca/books?id=HHZAFO2XiHMC&pg=PT236&lpg=PT236&dq=I%27m+sorry+for+the+bad+quality.+However+we+really+did+as+what+you+said.&source=bl&ots=WTPPWbsJC2&sig=475X3q6X4N3hDEjVEurfOgRi4FQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=32QUVYaQE7PIsATuj4GADg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=I%27m%20sorry%20for%20the%20bad%20quality.%20However%20we%20really%20did%20as%20what%20you%20said.&f=false

Comment: I see it too.  If you google the first couple of sentences (and put them in quotation marks), the only results you get are Google books and some sites that are devoted to hosting free copies of books.

Comment: It's not in the dead-tree version of the book. The second example was very easy to locate. In my copy there is no extra text between "I'm telling you [...] bloody little tart." and "What are you going to do, Dad, thump me again?"